# Fast Fourier Transform of Frequency Analysis in Labview

Tags: fft, sensors, labview, frequency-analysis

I'm currently measuring the signal from 3 direction vibration sensor. I wan to convert my signal to a FFT form to determine the frequency analysis of it. Anyone got idea how I do it in Labview?

Comment: This is most certainly not a programming question. You should look for another Stack Exchange site where it would be more suitable.

Comment: refer to the LabView user manual?

Answer (score 2):

There is an FFT VI under Signal Processing >> Transforms on the Functions Palette that should do what you're asking. Probably not a bad place to start.

[image: FFT.vi]

Answer (score 0):

Check out Signal Processing >> Waveform Measurements as well. This has slightly higher level functions which will work out all of the magnitudes and frequencies for you as well. These do require the full development system though.

Comment: Try using the add function to add the offset in your example and you should see it. Even with the very low frequency you have it is going in the first frequency bin.
Depending on the signal you can sometimes also get the DC offset with a simple mean function, but not sure if it is as accurate.

Comment: Do you have any example to show me? I using arduino uno with 10bit ADC. I'm detecting 4V+- amplitude from my analogue input. I would like to display this in FFT waveform.

Comment: The code you have already should work but you may have to count the bottom two bins as DC depending how much is true DC and how much is just very low frequency. See this mod: https://imgur.com/nZn2vYt

Comment: actually I wanna do it in a frequency analysis algorithm showing over here http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9230/en/#toc2. You got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I wan to use the DC component from my arduino ADC and compute it into FFT. I tried using this configuration as shows here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr5FP.png But the output of FFT i get doesnt seems much effect when sustained to huge voltage changes overtime in my ADC reading.

Anyone got better way to use FFT to compute the voltage signal from my ADC?